# iframe security risk when running over HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: iframe, https, security

BACKGROUND: I have a web app that is mainly served over HTTP example.com, example.com/faq, etc. are all served over HTTP.  These pages provide public information about the app, then when the user logs in, they go to https://example.com/account.  The /account page is ALWAYS served over SSL (HTTPS).  Note: I could serve everything over HTTPS, but the latency is slower and hurts the user experience.

THE IFRAME:  Here's where the iframe comes in.  The /account page uses secure cookies to store user data (session ID, User Name, User Score, Latest User Actions) and I want to keep those cookies up to date at all times (even when the user is on an HTTP page).  So, I embedded a 1px hidden iframe on all HTTP pages that points to https://example.com/account/update which contains the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            KEEP APP UPDATED
        </title>
        <script>
            (Include jQuery)
            setInterval(function(){$ajax('https://example.com/account/update/latest-user-data')}, 5000);
        <script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I should note that in order to allow this iframe, I need to disable the X-FRAME-OPTIONS on my server for this page.

QUESTION:  Are there any security issues with this?  Is clickjacking a major threat?  More importantly can an attacker access those secure cookies or gain access to the iframe Javascript variables, etc running in the iframe?

Comment: there's no need for this iframe. you can do https ajax requests from a standard http page without an iframe, and you can use intervals to make it a repeated request as well. Regardless of how you're doing it, you'd STILL be making https requests to the same server. Adding in an iframe just ads a minor bit of extra complexity. Anyone who can inject code into your page could access the cookies anyways.

Comment: Won't this violate the same origin policy (HTTP and HTTPS are different origins)?